# How to read data on a specific row from excel by asking the name of that row?

Tags: excel-2007

I have the following excel file:

```
W1000x554   1032    408 52.1    29.5    70700   12300   
W1000x539   1030    407 51.1    28.4    68700   12000   
W1000x483   1020    404 46      25.4    61500   10700   
W1000x443   1012    402 41.9    23.6    56400   9670    
W1000x412   1008    402 40      21.1    52500   9100    
W1000x371   1000    400 36.1    19      47300   8140    
W1000x321   990     400 31      16.5    40900   6960    
W1000x296   982     400 27.1    16.5    37800   6200    
W1000x584   1056    314 64      36.1    74500   12500
```

I want to define a function that can ask the user for one of the first column's names and then read all the relevant data of that row later.
For example if the user defines `W1000x412` then read : `1008   402 40  21.1    52500   9100`.
Any ideas?

Comment: Yes.  My idea is to use `VLOOKUP()`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what @Marc means is that a formula such as in `J2` below (copied across and down as necessary) will 'pick out' the values you want. It is not clear to me from your question whether these should be kept separate (as in `Row2` of example) or strung together (CONCATENATE [&] as in `J7` of example, where these are space [" "] delimited):

[image: SO13424984 example]

I am also not entirely sure about your 'define a function' but have assumed you do not require a UDF.

I have used `Row1` to provide the offset for VLOOKUP, to save adjusting manually the formula for each column.

`ColumnI` is the expected user input, that might be best by selection from a Data Validation List with Source $A$2:$A$10.